# Altering variable in a php file on a web server

Tags: php

The following is an excerpt of a PHP script within a HTML file.
I would like to be able to alter the variable when I am being served the HTML file. Is there anyway to do so? Most vulnerabilities i found online are exploits for $_GET.

```
if (isset ($_POST['variable']))
{$temp = $_POST['variable'];
if (strlen($temp) == 20)
{
 ....
} else echo "Failed";
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at curl, or a similar library:

```
curl -d foo=bar http://example.org
```

will send the request as a POST, with the variable `foo` set to value `bar`.

HTTP is a clear text protocol, fairly human readable. If you use a decent browser, like chrome, you can open the web developer console and watch all requests, including payload. In chrome you press F12 to open the developer console.

If you're interested in HTTP, read the relevant standards. Wikipedia is a good starting point.

Comment: Just writing some html or using a browser plugin like tamperdata would also suffice (a lot of people don't have a well equipped posix system to hand)

Comment: @symcbean turns out tamperdata isn't supported on newer versions of firefox, unless you have a workaround? ;)

Comment: My point was that there are *lots* of ways to do something as simple as setting the value of a post variable.

Comment: curl works equally well on windows. So does chrome. And if you're interested in security, *not having* a Linux system is gross negligence...

Comment: @vidarlo thanks for your help, it does work and i can enter the if loop. i've encountered another problem where the POST value does not stick if that's the correct way to put it. the first line in the loop i attempt to store the POST value in a variable. $temp=$_POST['variable']; this is not recognised.

Comment: That's impossible to debug with the information you've given.

Comment: @vidarlo i've edited my original code snippet to show more information. Essentially with the curl solution you gave i'm able to receive the "Failed" output. I am unsure why my variable which is now stored in $temp does not match the 20 character length.

Comment: Because it's not 20 characters in length. Print the strlen to see, and print the data to verify. You may be a victim of urlencoding or similar features.

Answer (score 2):

$_POST is just as vulnerable as $_GET. If this variable is not being sanitised and/or validated later in this script then you can manipulate it however you like.